# How to get preview buffer of MediaCapture - Universal app

Tags: windows, win-universal-app, windows-store

In Windows phone silverlight, I use PhotoCamera to get buffer frame when start preview video, in universal app I use MediaCapture instead, but I don't know how to get preview buffer.

Thanks

Comment: This answer is now being [used elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703586/camerapreviewimagesource-empty-preview-frame?lq=1) which suggests it is correct. If you agree could you accept it to help others with this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access preview frame from MediaCapture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947225/access-preview-frame-from-mediacapture)

Comment: Not a duplicate. That other answer is great, but I think it works only on Windows 10, and requires allowing unsafe code. My answer uses the Lumia Imaging SDK and has neither limitation (though I think it's much less efficient).

Comment: @Liero Windows 10 is not specified in the question title, nor in the tags. The question was asked in December 2014, but Windows 10 was not released until July 2015. Sadly Microsoft used the term "universal app" for cross-device apps in the Windows 8.1 era too. I think this is where the confusion comes from.

Your comment is still very useful. UWP apps have easy access to preview frames and I will add an answer pointing to that.

Comment: You are right. I deleted my comment so could you. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Since Windows Runtime doesn't have Silverlight's `PhotoCaptureDevice` class, the extremely useful `GetPreviewBufferARGB()` and `GetPreviewBufferYCbCr()` methods are not available.

The solution you're looking for is to use the `MediaCapture.StartPreviewToCustomSinkAsync()` method, but this requires C++ skills better than mine. No-one seems to have solved the problem and shared their code.

**Now there's a really beautiful solution**, using the [Lumia Imaging SDK](http://www.nuget.org/packages/NokiaImagingSDK/), that doesn't use the MediaCapture class, but will probably solve your problem even better.

Check out Microsoft's [example on Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/real-time-filter-demo/tree/master/RealtimeFilterDemoWindows) first. This works well but is quite complicated because it targets both Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1.

I've written some simpler code, just targeting Windows Phone, for my own understanding. It might help.

Start with a new C# Windows Phone 8.1 (Store) app with the Lumia Imaging SDK installed via NuGet PM. This example draws to an image element with `x:Name="previewImage"` in `MainPage.xaml` so make sure you add that. You'll also need to make the relevant imports to `MainPage.xaml.cs` which I think are.

```cs
using Lumia.Imaging;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using Windows.UI.Core;
using System.ComponentModel;
```

Then you just add the following in the right place in `MainPage.xaml.cs`.

```cs
private CameraPreviewImageSource _cameraPreviewImageSource; // Using camera as our image source
private WriteableBitmap _writeableBitmap;
private FilterEffect _effect;
private WriteableBitmapRenderer _writeableBitmapRenderer; // renderer for our images
private bool _isRendering = false; // Used to prevent multiple renderers running at once

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
    startCameraPreview();
}

private async Task startCameraPreview()
{
    // Create a camera preview image source (from the Lumia Imaging SDK)
    _cameraPreviewImageSource = new CameraPreviewImageSource();
    await _cameraPreviewImageSource.InitializeAsync(string.Empty); // use the first available camera (ask  me if you want code to access other camera)
    var previewProperties = await _cameraPreviewImageSource.StartPreviewAsync();
    _cameraPreviewImageSource.PreviewFrameAvailable += drawPreview; // call the drawPreview method every time a new frame is available

    // Create a preview bitmap with the correct aspect ratio using the properties object returned when the preview started.
    var width = 640.0;
    var height = (width / previewProperties.Width) * previewProperties.Height;
    var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)width, (int)height);
    _writeableBitmap = bitmap;

    // Create a BitmapRenderer to turn the preview Image Source into a bitmap we hold in the PreviewBitmap object
    _effect = new FilterEffect(_cameraPreviewImageSource);
    _effect.Filters = new IFilter[0]; // null filter for now
    _writeableBitmapRenderer = new WriteableBitmapRenderer(_effect, _writeableBitmap);
}

private async void drawPreview(IImageSize args)
{
    // Prevent multiple rendering attempts at once
    if (_isRendering == false)
    {
        _isRendering = true;
        await _writeableBitmapRenderer.RenderAsync(); // Render the image (with no filter)
        // Draw the image onto the previewImage XAML element
        await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High,
            () =>
            {
                previewImage.Source = _writeableBitmap; // previewImage is an image element in MainPage.xaml
                _writeableBitmap.Invalidate(); // force the PreviewBitmap to redraw
            });
        _isRendering = false;
    }
}
```

You might be wondering... how do I grab the previewBuffer? You don't need to!

The `_writeableBitmap` object always holds the latest frame from the camera so you can do whatever you like with it.

Comment: Should there be a line where the CaptureElement in the XAML is linked to the CameraPreviewImageSource ?

Comment: Hi Paulina, I don't think so. In this code example there is no CaptureElement in the XAML. Each time a new frame is available we call the drawPreview method to render it as a bitmap and then draw it to the previewImage image in the XAML. This is not very efficient, but it works and there seem to be some optimisation in Windows 10 that make it more efficient.

Comment: Thanks Thomas! :) Well, seems like starting from scratch is the way to go 'cause I had already used the MediaCapture object & CaptureElement all over the place >_<

Comment: Any clue as to why would I get an "Access denied" message when the _cameraPreviewImageSource.InitializeAsync is called?

Comment: Paulina -- have you enabled `Webcam` in `Package.appxmanifest>Capabilities`? That's my only guess.

Comment: Ah yes! Missing that one :) Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

My other answer is still valid for Universal Apps targeting Windows 8.1 -- but for those targeting Windows 10 with UWP apps there is a much simpler answer now.

[Grabbing a preview frame in UWP is easy and well-documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/get-a-preview-frame) -- from an existing MediaCapture object it can be done in three lines.

```
// Get information about the preview
var previewProperties = _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview) as VideoEncodingProperties;

// Create a video frame in the desired format for the preview frame
VideoFrame videoFrame = new VideoFrame(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, (int)previewProperties.Height, (int)previewProperties.Width);

// Grave a preview frame        
VideoFrame previewFrame = await _mediaCapture.GetPreviewFrameAsync(videoFrame);
```