# MediaCapture grab single frame

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I'm trying to grab a single frame by making use of the MediaCapture class. I've viewed various tutorials, but all of them focus on the easy stuff. I've also had a look at the following: [Access preview frame from MediaCapture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947225/access-preview-frame-from-mediacapture), but that tutorial focuses on Windows 10.

So, first question is, is this even possible? Secondly, if so, does anyone have some advice?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume from your tags that this is for Desktop? Because Phone has always had an API to capture preview frames (`PhotoCaptureDevice.GetPreviewBuffer*`, see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.phone.media.capture.photocapturedevice.aspx). Although keep in mind that Windows.Phone.Media.Capture is deprecated at this point.

On desktop, you might as well take a full picture. It won't be significantly slower, and because USB cameras generally have a single stream for all capture types (preview, photo, video, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.videodevicecharacteristic.aspx), which means all the streams will run at the same resolution.

Look into `MediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync()` or `CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync()`. More information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700840.